# Product URL missing category slug on production site

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft4, slug

I upgraded a Craft CMS 3 site to version 4. The Product URI Format for my products look like this:

[image: screenshot of slug format {productFamily.last.uri}/{slug}]

Before I re-save a product, the URL displays correctly the way it looked in Craft 3:

[image: correct URL]

But when I re-save, the path to the `productFamily` category is no longer displayed:

[image: wrong URL]

Any idea why this is happening? Is `{productFamily.last.uri}/{slug}` no longer a valid URI format? Or has this something to do with the [Entrification Plan](https://craftcms.com/blog/entrification)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `.last` is deprecated. The correct Product URI should be:

`{productFamily.inreverse.one.uri}/{slug}`

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that the Product URI format in production is the same as in development. If you are using Project config, you can look in your `config/project/commerce/productTypes/<your-product-type>.yaml` for the current file format in production.

If correct, you could try resaving a product in production and see if that updates the URL.

If resaving the product works to update the URL, you can resave all products in production with the command:

`php craft resave/products`

Which will update the URLs with the current URL format from product type settings.

Comment: The yaml-file does contain the same on prod (I really meant on dev-environment of hyperlane). '{productFamily.last.uri}/{slug}'. `php craft resave/products` does not do any difference

Comment: Just to elaborate: The difference is between ddev local development environment and any environment on the host. To make sure I didn't mess up a lot when going from local environment to host, I deployed all code and then overwrote the whole database via MySQL workbench so the dev on host would be equal to ddev

Comment: I suspect there's something wrong with the project config. When I rebuild the local project config so it matches the database, I get a lot of changes. When I deploy these changes, I am able to apply, but the process ends up in "A fatal error has occurred" with status: undefined and response: undefined.

Comment: please send in a support ticket to support@craftcms.com also recommend reading https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/project-config.html#adopting-project-config and https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/deployment-best-practices

Comment: Thanks. Have sent support ticket.

Comment: Please see updated question. Do you see a solution now?